# Getting Twitter mentions by date

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to get the mentions of a user from a specific range of dates?

I am trying this with no luck:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?trim_user=1&contributor_details=0&include_entities=0&since:2013-07-07

Answer (score 0):

This way don't work. You mast put in since parameter id of tweet you need.
Some like https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?trim_user=1&since_id=7873445649124096077